# Insertion Sort by swapping

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, sorting

I've just started to DSA, and had a question about insertion sort.

This the version from textbooks / tutorials.

```
void insertion_sort(int A[], int n) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        int temp = A[i];    
        int j = i;

        while (temp < A[j - 1] && j > 0) {
            A[j] = A[j - 1];   
            j = j - 1;
        }
        A[j] = temp;       
    }  
}
```

I was thinking would it make a difference, if we used `swapping` numbers instead of shifting the numbers and inserting the `temp` value in the correct hole position.

```
void insertionSort(int A[], int n) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        int temp = A[i];
        int j = i;

        while (temp < A[j - 1] && j > 0) {
            swap(A[j], A[j - 1]);
            j--;
        }
    }
}
```

Swap Code:

```
void swap(int &a,int &b){
    int temp = a;
    a = b;
    b = temp;
}
```

Oh, and it would be really awesome if someone could explain the Time Complexities of both.

Comment: They'll both be O(n^2). The swap for shifting is a nice touch.

Comment: Swapping involves considerably more assigents (by a constant factor) so its an important optimization.

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but both versions dereference memory before A[]. The comparison of `temp < A[j-1]` the first time through will have j=i=0, and dereference A[-1]. That's probably not what you want.

Comment: Oh I should have set `i = 1` in the outer loop I guess

Comment: `I've just started to DSA` - [DSA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DSA#Information_technology), [DSA](http://en.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=DSA)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proposed alternative is incomplete, you did not post the code for `swap()`.  In C, `swap` must be a macro and such a macro is easy to botch, whereas in C++, it can be a function that takes both arguments by reference.

Furthermore, you should test `j > 0` **before** dereferencing `A[j - 1]`. As posted, the code invokes undefined behavior.

Regarding your questions, both functions are equally slow with a time complexity of **O(N<sup>2</sup>)**, but the second is potentially slower because swapping involves more reads and writes than simply shifting the values by one position, but it could be faster on a sorted array because the first version has redundant stores.

Note that you can further simplify the code at the price of efficiency this way:

```
void insertionSort(int A[], int n) {
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = i; j > 0 && A[j] < A[j - 1]; j--) {
            swap(A[j], A[j - 1]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I used `swap()` with arguments as reference in C++ (forgot to mention).

Can you please link me to a page, where it explains swapping is slower than shifting, I'd really like to read it. (or maybe an explanation)

Comment: Post the code for your `swap()` function.  There are many ways to swap 2 integers: most will involve 2 reads and 2 writes, using an `XCHG` instruction is even more costly.  In contrast, shifting costs only a single read and write per step and a single write at the end.  As usual, the only way to assess code efficiency is to measure it! Given the quadratic complexity, a moderately large array will provide a good benchmark. Try different cases: sorted, pseudo-random, reverse order...

Answer (score 2):

Time complexity for both the approaches is O(N^2) in worst case. But number of operations in the second approach is more as compared to the first because second approach performs the same number of swaps as the number of shifts in the first approach but swap require 3 assignments as compared to just one in in **shift-based** approach. Hence, method proposed by you will be slower as compared to just shifting the elements.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdint.h>

void insertion_shift(int* arr, int n){
    int i,j,k;
    for(i=1;i<n;++i){
        int temp=arr[i];
        for(j=i;j>0 && arr[j-1]>temp;--j)
            arr[j]=arr[j-1];
        arr[j]=temp;
    }
}
void swap(int* a, int* b){
  int temp= *a;
  *a= *b;
  *b= temp;
}

void insertion_swap(int* arr, int n){
   int i,j,k;
   for(i=1;i<n;++i){
      int temp=arr[i];
      for(j=i;j>0 && arr[j-1]>temp;--j)
         swap(&arr[j-1],&arr[j]);
   }
 }      

void print_arr(int* arr, int n){
   int i;
   for(i=0;i<n;++i)
      printf("%d ",arr[i]);
   printf("\n");
}

int main(){
   int n;
   scanf("%d",&n);
   int* arr1= (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*n);
   int* arr2= (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*n);
   int i;
   for(i=0;i<n;++i){
      scanf("%d",&arr1[i]);
      arr2[i]=arr1[i];
   }

   struct timespec start, end;
   clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW,&start);
   insertion_shift(arr1,n);
   clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW,&end);
   uint64_t time_shift= (end.tv_sec - start.tv_sec)*1000000 +
                        (end.tv_nsec - start.tv_nsec)/1000;
   printf("using shift: %lld microseconds\n",time_shift);

   clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW,&start);
   insertion_swap(arr2,n);
   clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW,&end);

   uint64_t time_swap= (end.tv_sec - start.tv_sec)*1000000 +
                       (end.tv_nsec - start.tv_nsec)/1000;
   printf("using swap: %lld microseconds\n",time_swap);
```

}

Here is what I got when I called both functions on the same array of size 10000. [Compilation and execution for 10000 elements array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Liiui.png). If still not convinced, try to generate a random array of size 1000-10000 and run the above code to observe the difference.

Comment: Good timing code! May I suggest printing both timing after the benchmark to avoid any interference between the OS dealing with the display of the first line of outut and the timing of the `insertion_swap()`.  Also use 1000000LL to avoid integer overflow on architectures with 32-bit `time_t`. You might also try benchmarking different orders before the sort and use a pseudo-random number generator for easier adaptation to various array sizes.